# Not able to see DevOps team tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

When another team owner adds a DevOps tab to a channel and configures it to show a  Kanban board, the tab shows up for other members but displays nothing in the main window.  If I click on the **Go to website** link I can see the board just fine so it does not seem to be a permissions issue.

If that same member who cannot see content configures a new tab with the same configuration, they can see the board, but other members have the same issue with not being able to see the actual board in the content window.  So the only people who can see a DevOps tab pointing to a Kanban board are the people who create the tab.

Is this expected behavior or is there something wrong?

Comment: We have tried and we are able to see Devops tab screen without any issues. When you are trying did you get any login page or is it coming only blank page?

Comment: Just blank page.

Comment: Could you please try to open same tab in website and check if this page is,opening fine or blank page.

Comment: Yea it opens fine in website (devops).  Now it is showing in Teams as well.  Not sure why it started showing up.